# Replicate graphQL introspection query with a regular GraphQL query to avoid security risk (whilst using graphql-compose-mongoose)

Tags: graphql, introspection, graphql-compose-mongoose

Trying to get back a list of IdTypes from a graphQL query. Currently using introspection to get the list, however after a security audit we have been advised to disable introspection.

This is what I've currently got and obviously it doesn't work :(

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import { GQC } from 'graphql-compose';
import { composeWithMongoose } from 'graphql-compose-mongoose';

export const IdTypeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  idType: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['ID', 'Passport', 'None']
  }
})

const IdType = mongoose.model('IdType', IdTypeSchema)

export const IdTypeTC = composeWithMongoose(IdType, {})

GQC.rootQuery().addFields({
  idTypesMany: IdTypeTC.getResolver('findMany')
})
```

The enums are unlikely to change often.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't solve this - but here's what worked :D
Didn't need to involve mongoose at all...

```
import { GQC, Resolver } from 'graphql-compose'
import { validateSession } from '../authentication'
import { ID_TYPES } from './constants'

export function _idTypeResolveHandler () {
  return ID_TYPES
}

const idTypeResolver = new Resolver({
  name: 'getIdTypes',
  type: ['String'],
  resolve: _idTypeResolveHandler
})

GQC.rootQuery().addFields({
  idTypes: idTypeResolver
    .wrapResolve(next => resolveParams => {
      const { user } = resolveParams.context.state
      return next(resolveParams)
    })
})
```